# Docker connecting to container port after restarting docker

Tags: docker

So I am running mysql in docker container, using Desktop Rancher. And when I create container and keep Rancher up all is good and I can connect to it with my app as many times as I like, but when I restart Desktop Rancher I can't connect to container any more with my app.

This is what I use to create container: "docker run --name mysqldocker -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=humans -d mysql"

Now my question is what command do I need to run when after I restart Desktop Rancher so that I can connect again to it with my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

This will add the restart=always restart policy to an existing container that is named mysqldocker:

`docker update --restart always mysqldocker`

Also you could create a container initially with this flag so you won't have to update it after it is started:

`docker run --name mysqldocker --restart always -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=humans -d mysql`